# How to automatically close react-select menu once the last item has been selected? (empty list)

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Is there a built-in option or easy trick to auto close a `react-select` input once the user has selected the last available item?

I use the option `closeMenuOnSelect={false}` so that I can keep selecting choice (no menu close between them), but there is no need to keep it displayed with a "No item" message once I've selected all of them, I'd like it to close automatically.

I could implement such a behaviour, but it's redundant boilerplate, so I'm looking for built-in solution, but didn't find any at https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#props

---

> I've created a feature request for this https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3936

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a `react-select` functionality where you can set the props `noOptionsMessage` to `null` so the menu will close when there are no more options to select from.

```
// react component

<Select 
  ...
  isMulti 
  noOptionsMessage={() => null} 
/>
```

Documentation: https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select#props

Answer (score 2):

Here are 2 ways to go about it:

First is to use the `noOptionsMessage` prop which will close the component when no options are left to select:

```
<Select
    ...
    noOptionsMessage={() => null} 
/>
```

Second way is to achieve this by using the built-in `menuIsOpen` flag.

This way your select menu will remain open as long as you tell it there are options available:

```
// in your react component...

state = {
    isOptionsExist: /* code to determine if options are available  */
}

<Select
    ...
    /* pass in state param  */
    menuIsOpen={isOptionsExist}
/>
```

Comment: Although it's definitely doable like that, it's quite a lot of repetitive boilerplate of pointless state management that could be avoided. I'm not really looking forward manually managing the state of each input, there are quite a lot.

Comment: @Vadorequest you could just create your own component, which extends the `react-select` and includes this behavior. Then all the state management is contained in that enhanced select component

Comment: That's a viable alternative indeed.

Answer (score 1):

to close the menu on select you should use this prop

```
closeMenuOnSelect={true}
```

See https://react-select.com/advanced#action-meta

[image]

Comment: This feels like a Chat GPT answer. Would you mind bringing some reference?

Comment: you can go and check out this link https://react-select.com/advanced#controlled-props